# How is Maxfunevals used in the fit function of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

The `fit` function in MATLAB uses an input "MaxFunEvals" as an option to terminate the curve fitting. From the source code of it, it is not clear to me what it actually does.

From my understanding in every iteration step, it limits the maximal number of times the model function can be evaluated. Is that correct? So in total there are "MaxIter" x "MaxFunEvals" function evaluations at worst? Does this process somehow depend on the number of parameters? Could anybody even pin point me at the place in the source code of the `fit` function that uses "MaxFunEvals"?